# Block of text that surrounded by vertically spanning parentheses

Tags: scaling

For my beamer slides, I like to have a command that centers a block of text and surrounds it by parentheses whose vertical size grows as the number of lines in the text grows.

I currently have the following:

```
\NewEnviron{remarkblock}[1][]{%
  \scalebox{1}{%
     $\scaleleftright{(}{\parbox{0.95\linewidth}{\centering \small\BODY}}{)}$
  }
}
```

(don't ask me for explanations, I put this together from stackexchange bits)

This works almost fine. The only thing I'd like to improve is that when there is less than one line of text I would like the parentheses to not actually be 0.95 linewidths apart but just behave as normal parentheses (maybe a tad bigger) around centered text.

On https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes I read that replacing `\parbox` by `\pbox` should do exactly what I want. However, I have two problems:

1. If the text contains a manual line break, I get an error:
   `Somthings's broken -- Perhaps a missing \item`
2. If I don't have a manual line break, it kind of works, but the pbox becomes left aligned even if I put `\centering` before `\scaleleftright` as well as before `\pbox`

EDIT: Upon request, here is a Minimal Working Example. In this version, I get the error; if I remove the `\\` I get the left alignmnt, if I put a long text where the `test` is and remove the `\\` everything is as desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{1}{$\centering\scaleleftright{(}{\centering\pbox{0.95\linewidth}{\centering \small test \\ test}}{)}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @samcarter done

Answer (score 4):

EDITED based on jbfu's comments, to fix outcome in lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pbox,scalerel,stackengine}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\newcommand\myblock[1]{\noindent\hfill\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{{%
  \scaleleftright[.025\linewidth]{(}{%
  \pbox{\dimexpr0.95\linewidth}{\small\strut #1\strut}}{)}}}\hfill\mbox{}}
\begin{document}
\myblock{test}

\myblock{test\\test}

\myblock{test\\test\\test}

\myblock{\lipsum[1]}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \myblock{test\\test\\test}
\item \myblock{\lipsum[4]}
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `varwidth` package might be helpful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{varwidth}


\begin{document}
\centering

$\scaleleftright{(}{
\begin{varwidth}{0.95\linewidth}
\small test
\end{varwidth}
}{)}$

$\scaleleftright{(}{
\begin{varwidth}{0.95\linewidth}
\small test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{varwidth}
}{)}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I still get left alignment of the first bit with this

Comment: @Bananach Please see my edit. Is this the alignment you are looking for?  If not, can you make a sketch to show the desired result?

Comment: it is. however, optimally, I would like to have the centering included in the command block because I am creating an environment out of it

Comment: @Bananach You can include it in the definition of the `\newenvironment` without problem.